# Is there a way to create "empty" types to use for class templates?

Tags: c++

I have a class template that looks like this:

```
template <typename T>
class TextureIcon
{
    static std::unique_ptr<Texture> s_texture_;
public:
    static void setTextureFile(std::string&& filePath);

    static std::unique_ptr<TextureIcon<T>> instance();
private:
    TextureIcon();
    sf::Sprite sprite_;
};
```

The idea is that it can be used to create icons that all use the same texture, like this:

```
class FlowerTexture;

int main()
{
    TextureIcon<FlowerTexture>::setTextureFile("flower-texture.png");
    
    auto flower1 = TextureIcon<FlowerTexture>::instance();
    auto flower2 = TextureIcon<FlowerTexture>::instance();
    auto flower3 = TextureIcon<FlowerTexture>::instance();
}
```

This works as intended, but I'm a bit unsatisfied with the use of `class` to create the types to use for the different `TextureIcon`-classes, as it looks like forward declarations for classes that will be implemented later.

So I'm wondering: Is there a keyword for creating "empty" types with no implementation?
Something like this:

```
DefineType MyType;
```

Comment: `class FlowerTexture {};`

Comment: What is the point of the `T` parameter to your template? Why does it need to be a type?

Comment: you can also write `using FlowerTextureIcon = TextureIcon<struct FlowerTextureTag>;` which may be clearer about the intended use of this forward declared but not defined class.

Comment: @JaMiT What else could be it if not a type? I didn't know you could use templates with anything other than types.

Comment: @JensB Whoever taught you templates did you a disservice. See cppreference.com for information on [templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates) and [template paramaters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters). *As an example, [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is a template with a non-type parameter.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using types, you can use an `enum class` to create different texture enumerations and then have that enumeration type as a non-type template parameter for the `TextureIcon` class.  That would look like

```
enum class Textures { Flower, Leaf, Branch };

template <Textures T>
class TextureIcon
{
    static Textures s_texture_;
public:
    static void setTextureFile(std::string&& filePath);

    static std::unique_ptr<TextureIcon<T>> instance();
private:
    TextureIcon();
    int sprite_;
};

int main()
{
    TextureIcon<Textures::Flower>::setTextureFile("flower-texture.png");
    
    auto flower1 = TextureIcon<Textures::Flower>::instance();
    auto flower2 = TextureIcon<Textures::Flower>::instance();
    auto flower3 = TextureIcon<Textures::Flower>::instance();
}
```

This lets you declare all the different types of textures you want to support in one place and keeps the namespace from getting cluttered with a bunch of empty types.